# WKWebView app gets frozen after going to background

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I have `swift 4` mobile app with `WKWebView` that renders html page (quite simple angular app). Sometimes when I switch to another apps - camera, youtube etc and then I come back to my app - it has only background and nothing happens in it - it looks like it was crashed. I tried to do workaround:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive),
        name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
        object: nil)
    
    
    HTMLLoader.loadScenario(for: webView)
}

@objc func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
    webView.reload();
}
```

Here I've tried to reload the app every time it **becomes active** (which is fine in terms of UX as I have persistent state) but it didn't help to resolve the issue completely - sometimes I still have it frozen, which probably means the problem could be on `WKWebView` level - I assume otherwise it would be able to reload the page.

How do I debug this and maybe there are suggestions on how to reload the app after going to background? I'm fairly new to `swift` so even most obvious advices could be helpful, thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same problem unfortunately using webview_flutter. Can't figure out a way to consistently reproduce it though.

Comment: @Aulig I found a fix for my problem - I've discovered at the time when webview looks like frozen it has no valid url (it has null at that moment) so I match it with my expected pattern (or I match that its not null) when app comes from the background (there is a hook for it in swift) and I store and load the correct url each time the app goes to background / restores. I will post detailed answer later, but I'm not sure if this helps with flutter

Comment: thanks for getting back to me! I think my issue was the webview process terminating randomly. This answer helped me reproduce & fix it (by reloading the page): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71350041/is-webviewwebcontentprocessdidterminate-ever-called-for-an-app-running-in-the-ba/73609765#comment133749334_73609765

Comment: @Aulig glad you found the solution, but do make double check that its always in that state, because I afraid it could be only half of the issue - I also tried reloading and it helped with half of the problem, but I've found out that sometimes it offloads webview completelly while the app is in background (it depends on device, its load etc) and in this case if you'll reload - it will reload same `null` url - just keep in mind it could be this problem if you'll still see hangscreen again